# Python: Format placeholder multiple times for the same variable

Tags: python, string, format

I would like to perform both a padding and limit the number of decimal points of a variable that will be inputted into a string using .format. I have managed to limit the decimal places but I can't seem to add the padding as well. The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) wasn't much help. Below is a copy of my code.

```
print "Frame No. {:6d} Expected: {:7.3f}ms Actual: {:7.3f}ms Difference: {:7.3f}ms - ERROR".format(currentImage, expected_time, regression_obj.timeFromStart, (regression_obj.timeFromStart - expected_time))
```

The output here shows that there is not enough spaces between values. I would like all the values to be aligned.

```
Frame No.     17 Expected: 582.080ms Actual: 484.971ms Difference: -97.109ms - ERROR
Frame No.     18 Expected: 616.320ms Actual: 513.498ms Difference: -102.822ms - ERROR
```

Expected Output;

```
Frame No.     17 Expected:       582.080ms Actual:     484.971ms Difference:   -97.109ms - ERROR
Frame No.     18 Expected:       616.320ms Actual:     513.498ms Difference:  -102.822ms - ERROR
```

Comment: So the problem is that there isn't enough space in between values?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @wnnmaw Yes see the edit in the question

Comment: @tayfun The output should all be inline see the edit in the question.

Comment: Minor, but confused me for a second: "inline" means something like "embedded".  You mean "in line", or better, "aligned".

Comment: @DSM Sorry yes that is confusing. I mean that the output should be aligned with each other so that it will be easier to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `{:9.3f}`. The first digit is minimum width of the entire number, including the minus sign, decimal point and decimal digits.

In your example `-102.822` is already 8 characters, so it goes out of alignment when you specify width of 7.